# Getting Id of the files to feedItem and feedcomment

Tags: visualforce, soql

Can anyone tell me how to get the id of the feedItem files?
Like I want to know the id(ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId) of the files that are attached to the feeditem and feedcomment.
Please someone give me the soql for above usecase.

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this chain of queries can help you

```
String feedItemId = '...';
FeedItem feedItem = [
    SELECT RelatedRecordId
    FROM FeedItem
    WHERE Id = :feedItemId
];

String relatedRecordId = feedItem.RelatedRecordId;

ContentVersion version = [
    SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId 
    FROM ContentVersion
    WHERE Id = :relatedRecordId
];

String result = version.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId;
```

Comment: there is no ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId in Contentversion class

Comment: try to use through ContentDocumentId (this field must be in ContentVersion) and another one query

Answer (score 0):

I think below link may help you to understand the flow of the content Document and content Version relationship.still your question is not clear to me so i can't help you to give proper query but you can refer this link.

https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_content.htm#sforce_api_erd_content